# Magento addAttributeToFilter

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I'm using attributes to a product, `availablepostalcodes`. This is a multi-select, there are 3 options per product:
1234
2345
3456

Now after a post (form) on the categorypage i've `$_POST['postalcode']`, this contains 2345. But when i do this nothing will filter:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter("availablepostalcodes", array("finset"=>"5021"));


echo $_productCollection->load()->count();
```

The echo still shows 5, however it should be 1, cause one product has that available postalcode.

This is the product-list view `/catalog/product/list.phtml`

What do i miss or don't see?

**Edit:**

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                              ->getCollection()
                              ->addAttributeToSelect('availablepostalcodes')
                              ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $_productCollection->getAllIds()));
```

Then i get all the products again.

But when i do `$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter("availablepostalcodes", array("in" => array(5021')));` it still doesn't work

Comment: Hay you can print this result like that echo $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter("availablepostalcodes", array("finset"=>"5021"))->__toString(); . Result can help to you.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::__toString() in /home/drnjyser/domains/happentest.nl/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/vanhappen/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 42

Comment: The method `getLoadedProductCollection()` already has loaded the products from the database, so any `addAttributeToFilter()` after loading can't and won't have any effect on the result.

Comment: Maybe the collections `clear` method could unset the loaded flag so further filtering could be applied.

Comment: I did an edit in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a multiselect so you need to filter for the multiselect option id not the option value!

Answer (score 1):

try in instead of finset

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter("availablepostalcodes", array("in"=>"5021"));
```